# SSI to RS485 communication protocol

Tags: serial, plc, automation

How do I interface a positioning sensor with SSI interface with an OMRON safety PLC with only RS485 interface? I understand both are serial, but would I loose resolution if I interface it?

Comment: Digital is digital.

Comment: Is your RS485 4-wire or 2 wire???

Comment: Which Omron PLC is it?

Answer (score 1):

SSI is point to point serial communication method usually used to send information from an encoded sensor to a micocontroller or PLC. RS485 is a point to multi-point communication method that has a entirely different protocol, used to link microcontollers or  or PLC's into a network. To convert from one to to another, you would need to design a small circuit with a MCU that had a SSI transceiver and a RS485 Transceiver (either 2 wire or 4 wire), and write code that translated the two protocols.

HOWEVER, they do sell exactly such a device; here is one already made from HMK:
http://www.hmkdirect.com/shop/IV251/